# How to take output of function inside of 'for' loop and use it build dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, xml-parsing, iterator, api-design

I am writing a script to do some exploratory analysis. The script refrences an API for ID's and the API responds back with an XML output(**with no child objects**)

Script:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et


xml ='''    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<YM>
   <Version>xxx</Version>
   <ApiKey>xxx</ApiKey>
   <CallID>xxx</CallID>
   <></>
   <SaPasscode>xxxx</SaPasscode>
   <Call Method = "GetIDs">

   </Call>
</YM>
'''        
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post('url', data=xml, headers=headers)
```

Example output:

```
<Members>
<Sa.Members.All.GetIDs>
<YourMembership_Response>
<ID>1234</ID>
<ID>4321</ID>
</Members>
</Sa.Members.All.GetIDs>
</YourMembership_Response>
```

I take these ID's and plug them into another API call to get more information about the IDs, in the same script through iterative function that parses IDs from the above API call into another API call that gets information about each ID:

Script:

```
def xml_event_info(eventID):       
    xml ='''        
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <YourMembership>
       <Version>xxx</Version>
       <ApiKey>xxx</ApiKey>
       <CallID>xxx</CallID>
       <></>
       <SaPasscode>xxx</SaPasscode>
       <Call Method = "Profile.Get">
           <ID>{}</ID>
       </Call>
    </YourMembership>        
    '''        
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    r = requests.post('url', 
                      data=xml.format(eventID), headers=headers)        
    print(r.text)      




# BUILD XML TREE OBJECT    
dom = et.fromstring(r.text)

# PARSE EVENT ID TEXT AND PASS INTO FUNCTION
for i in dom.iterfind('.//ID'):
     xml_event_info(i.text)
```

Example output (many more XML objects then shown):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Response>
<ErrCode>xxx</ErrCode>
<ExtendedErrorInfo>xxx</ExtendedErrorInfo>
<Profile.Get>
<ID>xxxx</ID>
<WebsiteID>xxxx</WebsiteID>
<EmailBounced>xxx</EmailBounced>
<NamePrefix>xxx</NamePrefix>
<FirstName>xxx</FirstName>
</Profile.Get>
</Response>
```

I want to take the above example with its many XML attributes from the second API call and map them to a pandas dataframe. The issue I am having is that when I try to use the function `(xml_event_info(i.text))` call from inside the for loop found here,that holds the second API call output:

```
# PARSE EVENT ID TEXT AND PASS INTO FUNCTION
for i in dom.iterfind('.//ID'):
     xml_event_info(i.text)
```

I am trying to map the xml to map into the dataframe and I keep getting the error **'TypeError: Parse() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not None'**

**How can I parse XML output from multiple API calls into pandas dataframe, in which each XML tag is the header of the dataframe**

```
Example:

---|ErrCode|ExtendedInfo|ID|FirstName----
```

The script and website I am referring to get the job done is found here (http://www.austintaylor.io/lxml/python/pandas/xml/dataframe/2016/07/08/convert-xml-to-pandas-dataframe/)

Script:

```
def xml2df():
    tree = et.fromstring(xml_event_info(i.text))
    root = tree.getroot()
    all_records = []
    headers = []
    for i, child in enumerate(root):
        record = []
        for subchild in child:
            record.append(subchild.text)
            if subchild.tag not in headers:
                headers.append(subchild.tag)
        all_records.append(record)
    return pd.DataFrame(all_records, columns=headers)
```

Complete Script:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

xml ='''    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<YourMembership>
   <Version>xxx</Version>
   <ApiKey>xxxx</ApiKey>
   <CallID>xxx</CallID>
   <></>
   <SaPasscode>xxx</SaPasscode>
   <Call Method = "Events.All.GetIDs">
       <StartDate>2017/01/1</StartDate>
       <EndDate>2017/01/31</EndDate>
   </Call>
</YourMembership>
'''        
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post('url', data=xml, headers=headers)


def xml_event_info(eventID):       
    xml ='''        
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <YourMembership>
       <Version>xxx</Version>
       <ApiKey>xxx</ApiKey>
       <CallID>xxx</CallID>
       <></>
       <SaPasscode>xxx</SaPasscode>
       <Call Method = "Event.Get">
           <EventID>{}</EventID>
       </Call>
    </YourMembership>        
    '''        
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    r = requests.post('url', 
                      data=xml.format(eventID), headers=headers)        
    print(r.text)
    return r.text      




# BUILD XML TREE OBJECT    
dom = et.fromstring(r.text)

# PARSE EVENT ID TEXT AND PASS INTO FUNCTION
for i in dom.iterfind('.//EventID'):
     y = xml_event_info(i.text)

     for xml in y: 
         tree = et.fromstring(y)
         root = tree.getchildren()
         all_records = []
         headers = []
         for i , child in enumerate(root):
             record = []
             for subchild in child:
                 record.append(subchild.text)
                 if subchild.tag not in headers:
                     headers.append(subchild.tag)
                 all_records.append(record)
                 #print all_records
                 print pd.DataFrame(all_records, columns=headers)
```

EDIT:

TLDR:

how to make the output from the below function be mapped into a data frame with the xml elements as the header of the of the dataframe:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

xml ='''    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<YourMembership>
   <Version>xxx</Version>
   <ApiKey>xxxx</ApiKey>
   <CallID>xxx</CallID>
   <></>
   <SaPasscode>xxxx</SaPasscode>
   <Call Method = "GetIDs">

   </Call>
</YourMembership>
'''        
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post('url', data=xml, headers=headers)

def xml_event_info(eventID):       
    xml ='''        
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <YourMembership>
       <Version>xxx</Version>
       <ApiKey>xxx</ApiKey>
       <CallID>xxx</CallID>
       <></>
       <SaPasscode>xxx</SaPasscode>
       <Call Method = "Profile.Get">
           <ID>{}</ID>
       </Call>
    </YourMembership>        
    '''        
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    r = requests.post('url', 
                      data=xml.format(eventID), headers=headers)        
    print(r.text)
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Response>
<ErrCode>xxx</ErrCode>
<ExtendedErrorInfo>xxx</ExtendedErrorInfo>
<Profile.Get>
<ID>xxxx</ID>
<WebsiteID>xxxx</WebsiteID>
<EmailBounced>xxx</EmailBounced>
<NamePrefix>xxx</NamePrefix>
<FirstName>xxx</FirstName>
</Profile.Get>
</Response>
```

Comment: IMO, your question is quite verbose. Can you give a tldr; version. I'm having difficulty understanding what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: You are missing the 'M' in [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @EyuelDK added tldr

Answer (score 1):

`xml_event_info(eventID)` function is not returning anything, just add a `return` statement at the end and try again.

```
def xml_event_info(eventID):       
    xml ='''        
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <YourMembership>
       <Version>xxx</Version>
       <ApiKey>xxx</ApiKey>
       <CallID>xxx</CallID>
       <></>
       <SaPasscode>xxx</SaPasscode>
       <Call Method = "Profile.Get">
           <ID>{}</ID>
       </Call>
    </YourMembership>        
    '''        
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    r = requests.post('url', 
                      data=xml.format(eventID), headers=headers)        
    print(r.text)
    return r.text
```

Comment: that works, I can now work with the output of the function, but how do I build the dataframe from here?

Comment: I made a edit. I used your advice on the return, and created nested for loops to iterate through the last xml output to be placed into Dataframe. Dataframe is created but keeps getting hung up one xml call and does not make cycle through the whole for loop.

Comment: please see edit under 'complete script' section. Thank you

Comment: `dom = et.fromstring(r.text)` what is `r` here! Is it the first request's response or from the second one!

Comment: when i go to print 'dom', I get the response '<Element 'Response' at 0x1146d1610>'